# How to terminate thread where there are time-consuming task running in a worker thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a worker thread handling some time-consuming task. For some reason, it starts using `_beginthreadex` and `condition_variable` to wait for tasks. The code looks like:

```
void MyThread::worker()
{
  while(true)
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> ulk(mut_);
    cv_.wait(ulk, [this](){return !this->TasksQueueEmpty() || this->ShouldTerminate();});
    if(ShouldTerminate())
      break;
    auto task = GetTaskFromQueue();
    ulk.unlock();
    task.Run(); 
  }
}

void MyThread::terminate()
{
  unique_lock<mutex> ulk(mut_);
  SetTerminate();
  cv_.notify_one();
}
```

Here `task.Run()` is a very time-consuming job. I would like to terminate the worker any time I want without waiting. And it seems that `TerminateThread` may cause some resource handling exception. Is there a workaround?

Comment: "Stop a thread immediately" is impossible. It's decided by kernel, instead of you. If you really need to "stop immediately", I think you may need to redesign your project with multi processes, instead of multi threads.

Comment: If the `task.Run()` runs mostly at User Space and you redesign the function `task.Run()` with some mechanism such as the `cv_` that you've used, "stop immediately` may be possible.

Comment: This is a classic issue with worker thread pools. You want the thread(s) to cleanly exit, but they can't exit while they off doing a long running operation and not checking for the terminate condition. You have to invent a way for the code executed by `task.Run()` to either periodically check for an exit condition or receive some notification/event (if possible) that it needs to quit early.  TerminateThread is bad for all the reasons you cite, but isn't the necessarily end of the world this is part of your process's orderly shutdown sequence.

Comment: I should comment on my TerminateThread suggestion. Beware, if your thread is doing something critical that could disrupt the persisted state of your application (e.g. flushing the database, writing out the document to file, etc....), then this is a bad idea.

Comment: @selbie It is a part of thread pools indeed. What run in those tasks are some general functions binded by threads somewhere else, so it may not be easy to provide signal mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The terminate() function should additionally set a boolean flag that the task.run() function should check frequently enough to make the stopping quick.

Terminatethread() can leave the program state inconsistent. Mutexes that were held by the thread will be left locked and memory is left allocated and open files arent closed etc.